# SVN externals are missing when checking out subfolder in Jenkins pipeline script

Tags: svn, jenkins-pipeline

I have a svn repo where I want to checkout from a subfolder which has inherited svn externals properties from its parent folder. When doing the checkout from the top folder everything from the svn externals got checked out but when checking out only the subfolder these are missing. I am using SubversionSCM.

Is there any option I could add so that properties from a parent folder is checked in my pipeline script?

Answer (score 0):

I can only think about a scripting solution. You can just check multiple repositories for triggering the build but do not checkout anything.

Inside your "build script" you could do the actual checkout of all the repositories you need.